# Getting response from Codeigniter controller method using AJAX/JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, model-view-controller

This is what am trying to achieve, I have a function in controller that generates a random password and returns the same, on button click I want to capture the generated password and display it in the view (password field). Here is the jquery/ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#generate_password").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",    
        dataType: 'text',
        url: "http://127.0.0.1/public/admin/content/manufacturers/generate_password",                   
        async:false,
        success: function(resp){
            alert(resp); //this alerts BLANK
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
              console.log(xhr.statusText);
              console.log(textStatus);
              console.log(error);
          }
        });     
    });
});
```

Controller function:

```
public function generate_password($length = 9)
{
    return $password_str;
}
```

1. Is this the correct way to call controller method?
2. Why am I getting blank value on alert, even though when printed in php am getting correct value?
3. Coz it's in the admin area can that be the reason, don't think so but is there any interference because of tokens?

Comment: First: doing this over HTTP is obviously insecure. Consider requiring HTTPS.

Comment: Second: you can try divide-and-conquer to determine whether the client or server is failing. You could send a request manually with something like curl to see what the response is. At first glance, I don't see anything apparent in the ajax call, so that's why I first suggest that you take the client ajax out of the equation.

Comment: I understand your concern but just trying to get it right first then I'll work on the security aspect

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, it is going to work okay, however you can use json format(and just json_encode/json_decode will finish the job for you), not sending via GET method and some other modifications.
Are you sure that the url is correct, if you open it in your browser, what happens?

Comment: well I tried that too but in that case I get NULL instead on blank value, been trying too many options but the end result seems same, no output. Really wondering if am calling the controller method correctly or there is another method of doing it?

Comment: when I open the url directly it shows me blank page

Answer (score 0):

You have to `echo` the variable in your function in place of `return`. Because `return` returns the value to the caller whereas `echo` sends something to the browser. JavaScript will only understand data which is sent to the browser. So, edit your function code as follows:

```
public function generate_password($length = 9)
{
    echo $password_str;
}
```

On the other hand you should be doing this over HTTPS rather than HTTP as mentioned by @rodamn

Comment: Tried with echo as well but same result, like stated before the url is just for local system, live will be https

Comment: I think that your url is not correct. Try enabling `url_helper` and change your ajax url setting to `"<?php echo base_url()?>/Controller_name/Function_name"`

Answer (score 0):

Well strange but changing the url from:

url: "http://127.0.0.1/public/admin/content/manufacturers/generate_password",

to this:

url: "generate_password",

did the trick and everything is working fine now :)

Thanks everyone for their valuable inputs.